# Connect Docker python image to internet

Tags: docker, networking

I pulled a python image, debian based and I want to connect from there to internet

```
 docker pull python:3.10
 docker run --net=host -it python:3.10 /bin/bash
```

Once I'm inside, I tried to curl  a simple web site

```
 curl -v -k https://google.com
 *   Trying 172.217.168.46:443...
 *   Trying ::ffff:172.217.168.46:443...
 * connect to 172.217.168.46 port 443 failed: Connection timed out
 * connect to ::ffff:172.217.168.46 port 443 failed: Connection timed out
 * Failed to connect to google.com port 443: Connection timed out
 * Closing connection 0
 curl: (28) Failed to connect to google.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

it looks like the machine can resolve the DNS, but it can't reach the internet.
I'm behind a corporate VPN, Docker Desktop is running on Windows and there is a manual proxy configuration:

```
 web server: http://xxxxx:8080
 secure web server: http:/xxxx:9444
 bypass proxy settings: 127.0.0.1, localhost etc.
```

I've tried to disable the manual proxy and restart docker, but it makes no difference.
The powershell running docker has internet access, i.e. the same curl works.

I don't know what else to try. The Python image has no network tools other than curl.

Answer (score 0):

oh, I just found out!, I run docker without the host option and use the same proxy in the curl call:

```
 curl -x https://xxxxx:9443 ...
```

not sure why, I thought the host option would do exactly that...